# Metal depth test not working with multiple draw calls

Tags: metal

I've enabled depth testing in my Metal renderer, creating a MTLTexture with the `MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float_Stencil8` format.

I then create a depth attachment for my render pass:

```objectivec
renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.texture = textureDepth;
renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.clearDepth = 1.0;
renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.loadAction = MTLLoadActionLoad;
renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.storeAction = MTLStoreActionDontCare;
```

Finally, I set my depth stencil state for the encoder as usual:

```objectivec
[renderEncoder setDepthStencilState:depthStencilState];
```

Which is configured like so:

```objectivec
MTLDepthStencilDescriptor *depthStencilDescriptor = [MTLDepthStencilDescriptor new];
depthStencilDescriptor.depthCompareFunction = MTLCompareFunctionLess;
depthStencilDescriptor.depthWriteEnabled = YES;
depthStencilState = [gpu newDepthStencilStateWithDescriptor:depthStencilDescriptor];
```

I also make sure to configure my pipeline state descriptor with the correct depth pixel format:

```objectivec
pipelineStateDescriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float_Stencil8;
```

This is enough to get depth testing working for single draw calls. All of the vertices are rendered in the correct order.

Strangely though if I'm drawing multiple objects in separate draw calls, they still behave as if depth testing is not enabled. They render themselves just fine, but their depth is still dependent on the draw call order rather than their actual depth values.

In OpenGL it all works fine, and the correct output is shown below:

[image: OpenGL Render output]

In Metal however, I get the following output (notice the boxes are overlapping on the right):

[image: Metal Render output]

The left box is rendered first, followed by the two boxes to the right.

I've also looked in GPU Frame Capture at the depth buffer, and at a cursory glance it appears to be correct:

[image: Depth buffer]

Is there anything else I need to enable / configure to allow for the boxes to be sorted correctly based on their depth?

For my projection matrix, I create it like so, along with the model matrix (using AAPLMathUtilities for matrix functions):

```objectivec
  vector_float3 translate = {mesh->x, mesh->y, mesh->z};
  vector_float3 scale = {mesh->sx, mesh->sy, mesh->sz};
  matrix_float4x4 modelMatrix = matrix_multiply(matrix4x4_translation(translate), matrix4x4_scale(scale));
  vector_float3 eye = { item->camera_position.x, item->camera_position.y, item->camera_position.z };
  vector_float3 target = {
    item->camera_position.x + item->camera_front.x,
    item->camera_position.y + item->camera_front.y,
    item->camera_position.z + item->camera_front.z
  };
  vector_float3 up = { item->camera_up.x, item->camera_up.y, item->camera_up.z };
  matrix_float4x4 viewMatrix = matrix_look_at_right_hand(eye, target, up);

  auto modelViewMatrix = matrix_multiply(viewMatrix, modelMatrix);
  auto projectionMatrix = matrix_perspective_right_hand(radians_from_degrees(45.0f), screenWidth / screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

The shader calculates vertex positions like so:

```
float4 position = float4(in.data.xyz, 1.0);
out.position = uniforms.projectionMatrix * uniforms.modelViewMatrix * position;
```

Comment: What's the range of the depth you are outputting for metal? How do you create the projection matrix? The reason I'm asking is because in OpenGL the depth will go from -1 to 1, but in Metal it goes from 0 to 1

Comment: @JustSomeGuy I've updated the question with a bit more detail about the projection matrix. I'm using a depth range of 0.1f to 100.0f.

Comment: I tried switching to using GLM like in my OpenGL renderer and with the exact same projection matrix code I use in OpenGL I still get the issue, so I don't think it's anything to do with the projection matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that instead of using `MTLStoreActionDontCare` for the `renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.storeAction`, I should be using `MTLStoreActionStore`. This fixes the depth sorting and makes the render output consistent with OpenGL.

Comment: That only has an effect if you are writing depth in one command encoder and reading it in another. Are you doing a depth prepass?

Comment: @JustSomeGuy At the moment I have a 1:1 ratio between command encoders and draw calls, I don't use a depth prepass. Is this the wrong way to go about it?

Comment: making an encoder for each draw call is the wrong way to do it. You should render as much stuff as possible in one encoder. Then not storing the depth is not a problem. I can elaborate: each time you end an encoder, the driver will actually execute the store actions, and each time you start an encoder, it will execute all the load actions. That means, it will write and read the attachments for each draw call you have. The memory bandwidth is limited, so you won't be able to draw a lot of things in a short amount of time.

Comment: Rule of thumb is basically: use as little encoders as possible. End encoders only when you actually need the results that they produced to be used in some other place: meaning, compute encoder, or you need the whole texture to use in some other draw call. Otherwise, try to use programmable blending and tile shaders, if they are available on the platform, because they can give you a way to run sum processing without ending the encoder.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy thanks for the tip! Got a 20 FPS boost for free by switching to using one render encoder.

Comment: I recommend watching some of the WWDC videos on the topic, they go in-depth on reasons how this works. It'll help to make a better mental image of the rendering model when using Metal and in general